# Hide shipping address on local pickup in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

How do you hide the "Shipping Address" info section in the customers' processing email if "Local  Pickup" is chosen?

I don't know how to provide code for this.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes it's possible** *(see the update at the bottom of this page)* …

> [**overriding WooCommerce templates**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) (copying the WooCommerce plugin **`templates`** folder to your active child theme or theme, renaming it **`woocommerce`**). 
>   For that please [**be sure to read the related docs**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) **First**.

Once above correctly done, you have to edit 2 templates located in that **`woocommerce`** folder inside your active child theme or theme. the files are located in:

1. **`emails`** `(sub folder)` **> `email-addresses.php`** `(php file)`.
   Replace the code of this template **from line 19:**

```php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

?><table id="addresses" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%; vertical-align: top;" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="td" style="text-align:left; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" valign="top" width="50%">
            <h3><?php _e( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

            <p class="text"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_billing_address(); ?></p>
        </td>
        <?php // ======================> Here begins the customization

            $shipping_local_pickup = false;
            if ( $items_totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
                foreach ( $items_totals as $items_total ) {
                    if ( $items_total['value'] == 'Local Pickup' && !$shipping_local_pickup ) $shipping_local_pickup = true;
                }
            }
            // End

            if ( ! wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() && $order->needs_shipping_address() && ( $shipping = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address() ) && !$shipping_local_pickup ) : ?>
            <td class="td" style="text-align:left; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" valign="top" width="50%">
                <h3><?php _e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>

                <p class="text"><?php echo $shipping; ?></p>
            </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

2. **`emails`** `(sub folder)` **> `plain`** `(sub folder)` **> `email-addresses.php`** `(php file)`.
   Replace the code of this template **from line 19:**

```php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

echo "\n" . strtoupper( __( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ) ) . "\n\n";
echo preg_replace( '#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $order->get_formatted_billing_address() ) . "\n";

 // ======================> Here begins the customization

$shipping_local_pickup = false;
if ( $items_totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
    foreach ( $items_totals as $items_total ) {
        if ( $items_total['value'] == 'Local Pickup' && !$shipping_local_pickup ) $shipping_local_pickup = true;
    }
} // End

if ( ! wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() && $order->needs_shipping_address() && ( $shipping = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address() ) && !$shipping_local_pickup ) {
    echo "\n" . strtoupper( __( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ) ) . "\n\n";
    echo preg_replace( '#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $shipping ) . "\n";
}
```

---

I have jus added this to detect when **Local Pickup** is used in an order:

```
$shipping_local_pickup = false;
if ( $items_totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
    foreach ( $items_totals as $items_total ) {
        if ( $items_total['value'] == 'Local Pickup' && !$shipping_local_pickup ) $shipping_local_pickup = true;
    }
}
```

And this in the existing **`if`** statement to stop the display of shipping address (for Local Pickup):

```
&& !$shipping_local_pickup
```

---

> **Update:** Is possible to use a **much more compact code** using the [** WC_Abstract_Order class - `has_shipping_method()`** method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_has_shipping_method) this way:
>
> ```
> $shipping_local_pickup = false;
> if ( $order->has_shipping_method( 'local_pickup' ) )
>     $shipping_local_pickup = true;
> ```
>
> And this in the existing **`if`** statement to stop the display of shipping address (for Local Pickup):
>
> ```
> && !$shipping_local_pickup
> ```

---

References:

- [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)
- [Class WC_Abstract_Order - has_shipping_method()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#_has_shipping_method)