# WooCommerce - Hide shipping address when local pickup is chosen on thankyou page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I am using WordPress with WooCommerce plugin Last version on an e-commerce website.

I would like to hide the "Shipping Address" in WooCommerce "Order received" page when "Local Pickup" shipping method is chosen.

How can I achieve this?

Here is the screenshot Of the Order Received page:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible [overriding WooCommerce templates](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) *(copying the WooCommerce plugin templates folder to your active child theme or theme, renaming it woocommerce)*.

You can use the same code as [the answer of your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936283/woocommerce-hide-shipping-address-on-local-pickup-in-the-email/38937106#38937106), but in an other template: 
**`order/order-details-customer.php`** that is loaded on Thankyou WooCommerce page ("Order receive" page).

Replace in the portion of code **from line 64 to the end** on **`order/order-details-customer.php`** template with this code:

```
<?php
    // BEGIN HERE
    $shipping_local_pickup = false;
    if ( $items_totals = $order->get_order_item_totals() ) {
        foreach ( $items_totals as $items_total ) {
            if ( $items_total['value'] == 'Local Pickup' && !$shipping_local_pickup ) $shipping_local_pickup = true;
        }
    }
    // END

    if ( ! wc_ship_to_billing_address_only() && $order->needs_shipping_address() && !$shipping_local_pickup ) : // HERE TOO ?>

    </div><!-- /.col-1 -->
    <div class="col-2">
        <header class="title">
            <h3><?php _e( 'Shipping Address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
        </header>
        <address>
            <?php echo ( $address = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address() ) ? $address : __( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
        </address>
    </div><!-- /.col-2 -->
</div><!-- /.col2-set -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

**This is tested and fully functional code**

References:

- [Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)
- [WooCommerce - Hide shipping address on local pickup in the email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936283/woocommerce-hide-shipping-address-on-local-pickup-in-the-email/38937106#38937106)

Comment: Better thing is you can combine all your code together and make it as a plugin . And you can upload your plugin on official  wordpress plugin directory . It will be helpful to many users