# Hide shipping address on WooCommerce orders based on specific shipping methods

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, shipping-method

I have two flat rates (flat rate:1 and flat rate:2) I would like to hide the "Shipping Address" in WooCommerce Thank you page when "Flat rate:2" shipping method is chosen.

Trying to use something based on [WooCommerce - Hide shipping address when local pickup is chosen on thankyou page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38965854/woocommerce-hide-shipping-address-when-local-pickup-is-chosen-on-thankyou-page/38966002#38966002), but I'm stuck.

Can anyone give a some tips how to achieve this?

Woocommerce 5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

You can use this simple code snippet, to hide shipping address from orders based on specific defined shipping methods:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_needs_shipping_address', 'filter_order_needs_shipping_address', 10,  );
function filter_order_needs_shipping_address( $needs_address, $hide, $order ) {
    // Here set your shipping method instance Ids
    $targeted_instances_ids = array( 1, 2 ); 
    
    // Loop through "shipping" order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items('shipping') as $item ) {
        if( in_array( $item->get_instance_id(), $targeted_instances_ids ) ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $needs_address;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Note:** The shipping instance ID is the number after `:` in a shipping method rates ID. 
So for example for `flat rate:2`, the shipping instance Id is **`2`**.

Comment: First of all thanks for quick respond. I'm trying to add code but I received fatal error on line 9: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN). As I understand correctly if I set $ targeted_instances_ids = array (2); the shipping adress for flat rate 2 should hide on order page.

Comment: Thanks for your time. After I added propper code shipping address does not show up in flatrate 1 and flat rate 2. Only billing address is shown. [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvSMMyCQWuCEtT9XMN3OkguL264A?e=qAsQQT)

Comment: Ok thanks for your help I will investigate by me side what I can do. Maybe Im missing something earlier.

Comment: Finally I have fixed the reason why your code did not work for me. I had to change the values to  'add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_needs_shipping_address', 'filter_order_needs_shipping_address', 10,2  );

function filter_order_needs_shipping_address( $needs_address, $hide, $order ) {'

Comment: @Jeronimo Oups yes sorry!… Forgot to rename the function too… Updated