# WooCommerce - Hide billing address on local pickup on checkout page and email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do you disable the "Billing Address" info section if "Local Pickup" is chosen?
Or how I can change the values of billing address if "Local Pickup" is chosen?

I don't know how to provide code for this.

Comment: Have a look to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936283/woocommerce-hide-shipping-address-on-local-pickup-in-the-email/

Comment: You can't really disable billing address from checkout even if billing and shipping adresses are the same, because billing data is needed in woocommerce checkout process.